# Calculating the exact height needed to fill the browser height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On [this website](http://www.prozign.com.php53-17.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/), I'm trying to set a height for the main content area so it always fills the browser window height. Here is the simple code I'm using:

```
$(".top-of-nav").height($(window).height() - 40);
```

`top-of-nav` is the main area (where the cat image is), and 40px is the height of the nav bar in the bottom of the page which I'm subtracting.

The problem is that I'm getting vertical scroll bars in the browser even if I subtract more than 40px.

Comment: your `<body>` has `padding-bottom:70px` that's causing the scrollbars

Comment: Great observation, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`padding-bottom` of your `body` make the problem

```
body {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'm using in a project, and it works quite well:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var window_h = $(window).height();
    $('.viewport').css('height',window_h);
});
```

This takes the window height and sets whatever element to it's height, recalculated whenever the window resizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
document.documentElement.clientHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I misread the question...

```
.top-of-nav {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    background: url(/media/1920x1080.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```